# Dificuldade em posicionar controles com bootstrap

Tags: c#, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um `cshtml`, que precisa posicionar alguns controles. Posicionei uma tabela ao lado esquerdo do documento. Agora preciso posicionar vários controles `labels` ao lado da tabela e esses `labels` um em baixo do outro. A minha tabela já ocupa `4 células`, já que o `bootstrap` divide em 12. Preciso carregar uma série de `2 labels` uma ao lado de outro e em baixo mais duas séries uma ao lado do outro e assim por diante.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você quer dizer por "label"? Está confusa sua explicação.

Comment: O que eu sinto falta nesta pergunta é: `(1)` O código, se você já tentou fazer alguma coisa; e/ou `(2)` Uma imagem (pode ser feita no paint mesmo) mostrando onde você quer o posicionamento de cada componente, pois pela tua explicação não deu pra entender.

Comment: `(3)` Nem sequer percebi onde está o problema. Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema, ou algumas imagens.

Comment: Ao ler pela quinta vez, o que queres é por  tabela(4) - label(4) - label(4) totalizando as 12 celulas?

Comment: Tens de copiar o código mesmo a mão para o editor ou fazer um print do que queres.

Comment: Ou se você quer em forma de imagem, tire um print.

Comment: tecla `Print Screen` do teclado

Comment: pnet, perdoe a franqueza, mas suas perguntas estão demonstrando cada vez menos esforço na explicação e exposição do problema :/

Comment: Não entendi brasofilo. Como assim menos esforço? Me desculpe a franqueza também, mas isso você não tem como medir. Sei que eu posto muito, acho que isso pode levar a esse tipo de atitude, mas não é verdade o que vc está me dizendo. Com todo respeito a vocês, estou lendo a documentação do twitter bootstrap e já postei em vários foruns, porque ainda não consegui resolver.

Comment: pnet não é desse esforço que o @brasofilo fala. É esforço para criar uma pergunta estruturada e percetível.

Comment: Claro, desculpe pela falta de clareza o_O Me refiro à **[ask]**. Vlw, @JorgeB

Comment: Ok, acho que não vale a pena ficarmos aqui debatendo coisas fora do escopo. Qjuero contribuir sim e não discutir. Peço desculpas a todos às vezes pelas palavras, mas o intuito é esclarecer, agora ficar colocando coisas fora do escopo não nos leva a lugar nenhum. Paro por aqui.

Comment: pnet o caso nem é esse. O caso é que esta pergunta poderia/poderá ajudar outras pessoas. E se a pergunta não for clara, vai desviar os utilizadores do que realmente importa.

Comment: Ok, vou procurar melhorar. Agora às vezes é o que vem a mente e não conseguimos perguntar de outra forma, entende. O que realmente pequei, foi em não ter colocado uma imagem. É mais claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você tem uma tabela e quer manter ela alinhada a esquerda e uma coleção de labels alinhados a esquerda da tabela, contudo você deve ter apenas dois labels por linha. 
Se entendi a estrutura que você quer, a grosso modo seria semelhante a abaixo:

```
<div class='pull-left col-sm-4'>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>1</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>3</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class='pull-left'>
    <div >
        <label>Label1</label>
        <label>Label2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Label3</label>
        <label>Label4</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Label5</label>
        <label>Label6</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Label7</label>
        <label>Label8</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Acredito que esse exemplo, já lhe sirva, contudo, para obter informações sobre alinhamento você pode consultar a [documentação do boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), você pode testar online o seu código usando o [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), os alinhamentos esquerda e direita usando as classes pull-left e pull-right se estiver usando o boostrap.

Comment: Não li nada sobre essa classe pull-left. Valeu a todos.

Comment: Só me tirem uma dúvida. Por default os labels vem em negrito sempre?

Comment: Não é bem negrito e sim font-weight: 700;